# I want to be able to scale my webpage down/up for different size screens

Tags: html, css, scalability

I tried adding  but didn't see any results...

Any help is appreciated.

Photos show its full screen and then down into lower/smaller screens and it scales really bad
Below is it in smaller screen.
[Here is the picture full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7u8h.png)[image: Here is it when the screen/window is smaller, cuts off a lot of the log in]

```
`<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Wishr Login Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="heading">
    <h1> Wishr</h1>
    <h2>Shopping made easy.</h2>

</div>

  <div class="login">
      <h1> Welcome!</h1>
      <h2> Login to start saving.</h2>
      <form>
         <p>Username:</p>
         <input type="text" name="usern" placeholder="John123">
         <p>Password:</p>
         <input type="password" name="passw" placeholder="********"> <br>
         <a href="#"> Forgot Password?</a> </br>
         <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">

       </form>
        <h3>Don't have an account?</h3>
        <input type="button" name="Signup" value="Sign Up">
    </div>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: We need to see your styling (CSS). Try to give a working snippet so we can try it out, see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help without having the CSS code, but I would recommend hiding the "Wishr shopping made easy" box, when the screen is too small.
You can do this by adding something like:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { #wishrDiv { display: none }
}`